# Filling object with zeros

Tags: javascript, object, initialization

I have some function that counts the number of certain elements in the array:

```
let array = [5,1,2,3,4,7,2,1,2,3,4,5];

function countEntries(arr){
    let entries = {};

    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        entries[item] += 1;
    });

    console.log(entries);
}
```

But the default values are not defined and this is what I get:

`{ '1': NaN, '2': NaN, '3': NaN, '4': NaN, '5': NaN, '7': NaN }`

I tried to define the properties of an object inside `forEach`:

```
arr.forEach(function (item) {
    entries[item] = 0;
    entries[item] += 1;
});
```

But in this case the property is reset to zero at each iteration. What should I do if I don't know in advance the names of the properties of the object?

Comment: In your `forEach`, try checking the value before incrementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track! All you need to put the condition inside forEach:

```
entries[item] ? entries[item] += 1 : entries[item]= 1;
```

Means if the item is already in the "entries" object, then increase the number, if not - assign 1.

The full code is:

```
function countEntries(arr){
 let entries = {};

 arr.forEach(function (item) {
  entries[item] ? entries[item] += 1 : entries[item] = 1;
 });

 console.log(entries);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add default value conditionally ( you can use logical OR )

```
entries[item] = entries[item] || 0
```

---

```js
let array = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function countEntries(arr) {
  let entries = {};

  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    entries[item] = entries[item] || 0;
    entries[item] += 1;
  });

  console.log(entries);
}

countEntries(array);
```

Comment: You can combine the `+= 1` after the initial assignment by putting the assignment in parens. Also, a semi-colon is needed at the end of that line.

Comment: @computercarguy yes can be done, but writing one extra line doesn't cost much, here IMO it stays quite readable and easy to debug if i keep it seperate

Comment: Sure. I just thought I'd add the comment in case the OP didn't know it was an option.

Answer (score 1):

or simply :

```js
let array   = [5,1,2,3,4,7,2,1,2,3,4,5]
,  entries = {}

for(let e of array) entries[e] = (entries[e]) ? (entries[e]+1) : 1


console.log( JSON.stringify(entries) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const countEntries = array => 
  array .reduce ((a, n) => ({...a, [n]: (a[n] || 0) + 1}), {})

let array = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console .log (
  countEntries (array)
)
```